# How to reconfigure kernel with PM_RUNTIME=y?

Tags: linux, kernel, kde, power-management, kde-neon

`tlp-stat` tells me to do the following:

```
+++ Recommendations
 * Reconfigure your Linux kernel with PM_RUNTIME=y to reduce your laptop's power consumption.
```

And i have no idea how I am supposed to do this.

Machine Info:
CPU: Intel Core i5-1135G7 
Model: Lenovo Ideapad Slim 5 
RAM: 16 Gigs 
OS: KDE Neon 5.24 
Kernel: 5.11.0-43-generic (64-bit)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That’s a long-obsolete recommendation — [`PM_RUNTIME` was removed in 2014](https://git.kernel.org/pub/scm/linux/kernel/git/torvalds/linux.git/commit/?id=464ed18ebdb6). Check your kernel for `CONFIG_PM`, most distribution kernels enable it by default.

Comment: Accepting it as the answer as this might help others with the same suggestion

Comment: I’ve added an item to my todo list to look into the warning and get it fixed one way or the other (either it should reference `CONFIG_PM`, or it’s indicating some other problem and should reflect that).